# proof for polynomial identity $x(x-a)^{n-1} = (x-a)^n + a(x-a)^{n-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm trying to find a proof for the polynomial identity

$x(x-\lambda)^{n-1} = (x-\lambda)^n + \lambda (x-\lambda)^{n-1}$

been trying for a while but I can't seem to see anything in this. I'd appreciate help a lot!

Comment: If you want to start from the left side, write the first $x$ as $x=(x-\lambda) +\lambda$

Comment: $(x- \lambda)^{n}= (x - \lambda) (x- \lambda)^{n-1}$.

Comment: Also, give your try the next time you ask questions.

Answer (score 2):

From the RHS, take $(x-\lambda)^{n-1}$ common like $$(x-\lambda)^n +\lambda(x-\lambda)^{n-1} \Rightarrow (x-\lambda)^{n-1}[(x-\lambda) +\lambda]\Rightarrow x(x-\lambda)^{n-1}$$ This expression is the LHS and hence the proof is completed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If we take out   $(x-\lambda)^{n-1} $common from RHS, we will have $(x-\lambda)^n + \lambda (x-\lambda)^{n-1}  =\ (x-\lambda+\lambda)(x-\lambda)^{n-1} =\ x(x-\lambda)^{n-1} $

Answer (score 1):

Take an $$(x-\lambda)^{n-1}$$
Out of the right hand side to get $$(x-\lambda)^{n-1}((x-\lambda)+\lambda)$$

Answer (score 1):

Fctoring out $(x - \lambda)^{n -1}$ yields

$(x - \lambda)^{n} + \lambda(x - \lambda)^{n -1} = (x - \lambda)^{n -1}(x - \lambda + \lambda) = x(x - \lambda)^{n -1}$.